# Fill Html Selection "FontSize" by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, selection

I want to fill my Selection by Script. I am struggling with the filling method.

When I want to fill my FontSizeMenu I use this code:

```
function FillFontSizeMenu() { // run this at Start
  FillSelection(GetPossibleFontSizes(), "fontSizeMenu"); // Fill the selection with values
}

function GetPossibleFontSizes(){ // Return all values for the menu
  var sizeMin = 1;
  var sizeMax = 100;
  var possibleSizes = [];
  for(var i = sizeMin; i <= sizeMax; i++)
  {
    possibleSizes.push(i);
  }
  return possibleSizes;
}


function FillSelection(possibleValues, elementId){ // Fill the menu
  for(var i = 0; i < possibleValues.length; i++)
  {
    var optionElement = "<option></option>"; // add one option element per value
    optionElement.html(possibleValues[i]);
    optionElement.val(possibleValues[i]);
    $(elementId).append(optionElement); // add the option element to the selection
  }
}
```

Something is wrong with the "FillSelection" method, it says the option element is not a function.

Does someone knows what is wrong or missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more solution
You need to create new Option object

```
 $(elementId).append(new Option("Font size "+i, possibleValues[i]));
```

and you should pass `#id` to function:

```
FillSelection(GetPossibleFontSizes(), "#fontSizeMenu")
```

```js
function FillFontSizeMenu() { // run this at Start
  FillSelection(GetPossibleFontSizes(), "#fontSizeMenu"); // Fill the selection with values
}

function GetPossibleFontSizes(){ // Return all values for the menu
  var sizeMin = 1;
  var sizeMax = 100;
  var possibleSizes = [];
  for(var i = sizeMin; i <= sizeMax; i++)
  {
    possibleSizes.push(i);
  }
  return possibleSizes;
}

function FillSelection(possibleValues, elementId){ // Fill the menu
  for(var i = 0; i < possibleValues.length; i++)
  {
    $(elementId).append(new Option("Font size "+i, possibleValues[i])); // add the option element to the selection
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="FillFontSizeMenu()">Populate it</button>
<select id="fontSizeMenu">
</select>
```

Comment: Is it possible to store Colors too? When i have a Selection with Colors like this way: https://hastebin.com/irihamedom.js

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `html` string in `jQuery()`

```
var optionElement = $("<option></option>");
```

You can also use `jQuery()` to set `html`, `value` and call `.appendTo()`

```
$("<option></option>", {
  html: possibleValues[i],
  value: possibleValues[i],
  appendTo: $(elementId)
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) That seems fine

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an element first then append properties using jquery. Something like this

```
var ele = document.createElement("<option>");  
 $("body").append(ele);   
 $(ele).html(possibleValues[i]);
 $(ele).val(possibleValues[i]);
```